# Как создать корзину в телеграм боте на питон

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telegram, telebot

Пишу телеграм бота на питоне как интернет консультанта.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

хочу чтобы после нажатия кнопки на "Выбрать" товар добавлялся в корзину и бот отвечал "Выберите количество товара".Но проблема в том, что пока нет корзины. Вот и суть вопроса, как сделать корзину чтобы туда добавлялся товар?
Вот фрагмент кода

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса

Answer (score 1):

можно использовать словарь:

```
basket = {'название товара': количество}
```